# Wrong Alt+Tab menu icon & text for Wine apps

Tags: wine, icons

I have Wine 1.4 installed but for some reason its Alt+Tab menu entry doesn't show the normal Wine icon. There is a generic 'document' icon with the text "Uninstall". What should I do to get the original icon and text?

[image: Alt+Tab menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was probably some leftover value from a messed up installation of Picasa. I just did the most obvious thing - removed everything related to Wine and reinstalled.